# make image corner round with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

i am using `jquery.imgr.js` to make image corner round in php file.

i have bellow code to generate images from database.

```
<?php 
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
{
?>
<img id="hero" src="art/<?=$getArtistsId[$i];?>"  height="75px" width="98px"/>
<?php
}
?>
```

bellow is script to make image corner round

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hero").imgr({size:"2px",radius:"10px"});
    })
    </script>
```

it works but only make the first image corner round not all.

1. how to make all image corners round?
2. is there any other batter and efficient way to make image round corners.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ID is unique, you are setting an ID for many elements so of course when you set the `imgr` script to run on the element with that ID it will only match one. Classes can be used on many elements. So instead of:

```
<img id="hero" src="art/<?=$getArtistsId[$i];?>"  height="75px" width="98px"/>
```

Use:

```
<img class="hero" src="art/<?=$getArtistsId[$i];?>"  height="75px" width="98px"/>
```

And then for the javascript use the `class` selector which is similar to CSS:

```
$(".hero").imgr({size:"2px",radius:"10px"});
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you explain why that should make a difference?

Comment: Because an `id` must be unique to an element. A class can be applied to a group of elements.

Comment: @mblase75 Ids are supposed to be unique, so if there are multiple of the same the selector will only apply to one.

Comment: Ah. I read the question as "only the first corner is round," not "only the first image has rounded corners."

Comment: @mblase75 [Because ID attributes are supposed to be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). jQuery also only returns the first element matching an id selector.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding and `id` in your loop, add a common `class`.

`<img class="hero" src="art/<?=$getArtistsId[$i];?>"  height="75px" width="98px"/>`

`$(".hero").imgr({size:"2px",radius:"10px"});`

Answer (score 0):

After adding a class, why not just?...

```
.hero img{
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming it's because border-radius isn't cross browser compaitible. [This plugin](http://www.steamdev.com/imgr/) is apparently very cross browser compatible and does actually use `border-radius` if supported.

Comment: The sooner we stop supporting bad browsers the sooner they die, yay.

Comment: @fancy: Well, yes, *obviously* users with old computers are much more likely to buy new ones just because they can't see pretty rounded corners on this guy's webpage. But maybe, just maybe, there's a user out there who doesn't have a choice in what browser they're using. We need to show compassion for these users, or they might, in their anger, turn to a life of crime, spray-painting the monitors of library computers in order to get the visual layout they so deeply desire. Do you want to be responsible for that? I, for one, do not.